# Subsequence classification

Tags: nlp, bert

Given multiple paragraphs, is it possible to classify an entire paragraph while taking into account the surrounding paragraphs?

```
Paragraph1

Paragraph2

Paragraph3
```

I am thinking of average pooling the token embeddings from a specific paragraph. This seems uncommon as I wasn't able to find examples of this online.

It is not quite the same as NER, since we know where the paragraph begins and ends. If using sequence classification on the paragraph, it wouldn't take into account the surrounding text.